# vue 2.7 vuex store is missing and throwing an No overload matches this call. error

Tags: vue.js

i recently updated our vue project to vue 2.7, however the vuex store seems to be broken and i don't have a clue whats causing this issue.

in main.ts

```
new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

The Error is:
No overload matches this call.

```
 Overload 1 of 3, '(options?: ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps<Vue, object, object, object, never, {}> | undefined): CombinedVueInstance<Vue, ... 4 more ..., {}>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ router: VueRouter; store: Store<any>; render: (h: CreateElement) => VNode; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object & ComponentOptions<Vue, DataDef<object, Record<never, any>, Vue>, object, object, never[], Record<never, any>, {}> & ThisType<...>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'store' does not exist in type 'object & ComponentOptions<Vue, DataDef<object, Record<never, any>, Vue>, object, object, never[], Record<never, any>, {}> & ThisType<...>'.
```

Has anyone a clue how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add

```
Vue.use(Vuex);
```

before calling

```
new Vue({
...
```